# Reading and sorting multiple files

Tags: java, file, sorting

Here is the complete problem I am having issues with:

> **Sort names without duplicates:** Write a program that reads the names from all ten files, sorts all names (boy and girl names together, duplicates removed), and stores the sorted names in one file ten per line (only names, no ranks).

The files show baby names and their ranking. An example file is set up like this:

```
1 Lewis 12,000 Sarah 50,000     //rank, boy name, amountBoy, girl name, amountGirl
```

The first step would be reading from the ten files. How can I do that without creating a new `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` for each file? Please point me in the right direction. I'm NOT asking for a complete solution.

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: *How can I do that without creating a new Scanner or BufferedReader for each file*: what's wrong in doing that? You're ruling out the obvious, correct solution.

Comment: So, should I sort each individual file then write all the files separately to the new file?

Comment: No. That's not what you're being asked to do. Read your assignment.

Comment: Hey, no need for the attitude. I'm just asking for a push in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

After you read one of the files and close the `BufferedReader` you can use the same object by settng its value to `new BufferedReader()`.

First you need to save all the names into an `ArrayList`. The next step is to copy the names into the second `ArrayList` and checking every name for duplicates.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public List<String> sortNames(List<String> names){
List<String> returnValues = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean exists = false;

for(String name : names){
   sub: for(String nm : returnValues){
      if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nm)){
         exists = true;
         break sub;
      }
   }
   if(!exists){
      returnValues.add(name);
   }else{
      exists = false;
      continue;
   }
}

return returnValues;
}
```